# What if I just start using SO for my own opensource API's FAQ?

Tags: discussion, instant-self-answer

I just came to think about this hypothetical situation, try to imagine with me.

You've just created a new programming API or library. I've got the impression that there's 1 new API and 5 new libraries every hour now, so I'm sure you've made at least one. You created a public repository, for example on GitHub a HTML documentation and some examples.

Now there are several questions that you know will be asked but don't fit into documentation (e.g. the answer is there but not explicit). So you decide to just start writing self-answered questions on SO tagging them with your API name.

Is that alright, even if noone knows the API at that moment? If so, would the moderators even be able to tell real API from fictional (this is not the main point of this question, but just imagine the situation...)? Have you done this or used API that chose SO for their FAQ source?

Comment: Also consider scenario where API is not public? How does that change the situation? Or what if the API is not public but was in the past, however the answers relate to the new version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Question you link as duplicate is actually answered in Help center, which I've read. But I was asking how much does it matter if noone actually knows the API - if there's a possibility nobody will be able to verify corectness of that content.

Comment: Also there's a difference between FAQ and Q&A.

Comment: In which way is _"There has to be some existing questions about your product on the site, preferably tags specific to your product to accompany them. It's generally best if these come from our community, we advise against seeding the site with questions about your product. Our community is very sensitive to spam and might see your attempt as such."_ unclear. I think this applies as well for Open Source products.

Comment: _"Also there's a difference between FAQ and Q&A."_ Sure there is. That's exactly what's addressed in the citation above. There have to be existing **frequent questions**.

Comment: It's much more clear now, except I think those existing question might be easily forged - at which point this request loses any reason. If somebody wants to, they will simply make it look like someone else asked those question. It just add additional discomfort to everyone.

Comment: Sure you can fake a community (although I don't think you'll get very far with that approach.) Our guidelines just state what a responsible product owner is being asked to do, in the interest of the site as well as their own product - an organically grown community is just so much preferable to some artificial Q&A

Comment: If you were creating an API and aware of shortcomings in the docs you were writing, wouldn't you just fix them in the docs?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as I said in the question, the answer might be there, but not in the FAQ format, and definitelly with much worse SEO. Just think about it, when you search for programming problems, what pops out first? Stack overflow or the actual documentation? Many times I actually clicked on stack overflow only to get documentation link as an answer...

Comment: @TomášZato I'm one of those irritating people who actually bothers to read the docs *before* deciding they need help... And you can always add an FAQ page to your existing docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're just dodging the topic. I understand I can add FAQ to my docs, or for example use GitHub issues for that, but my question was whether SO is another option or not. And by FAQ I meant specifically questions and answers written by same person, often based on documentation - because most people do not seem to bother reading it so much, otherwise SO would be way less popular.

Comment: I think it's kind of pointless to pontificate on hypotheticals, but if you insist: it wouldn't be a problem, *per se*, as long as the content was not obviously bad (well-written/formatted). You have enough rep to not get new posts reviewed, so probably nobody would see it until they searched for it. And those that do see it, as they can't judge the correctness either way, are unlikely to vote either way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was more curious about the moderators. I guess they too wouldn't notice 10-20 new posts, but they might notice new tag. Of course, if I really was about to do that I'd just send an email or ask in chat.